# Deploying Cloud Run via YAML gives error spec.template.spec.containers should contain exactly 1 container

Tags: google-cloud-run, knative

When deploying a Cloud Run service via a YAML file from the command line, it fails with this error.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.run.services.replace) spec.template.spec.containers should contain exactly 1 container
```

Comment: Your question does not show the YAML that generates the error. Update your question to show how the error was generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the documentation for adding an environment variable is wrong, or confusing at best.

The `env` node should be a child of the image and not the `containers` node as it says here.

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/environment-variables#yaml

This is correct:

```
  - image: us-east1-docker.pkg.dev/proj/repo/image:r1
    env:
    - name: SOMETHING
      value: Xyz
```

Comment: Show the original YAML and the changes necessary that solved your problem.

Comment: What about when using "envFrom.secretRef"?